# No Route Matches Custom Controller Action with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I am attempting to build a custom controller action that would receive parameters from ajax in the controllers related coffeescript file.

However the console notes error 404 and cannot access that route:

[image]

How can I configure this to make the routing and action work?

Controller action on campaigns_controller:

```
def create_campaign_location_relationship
    @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])

    @insert = CampaignLocation.new(campaign_id: @campaign.id,
                                   location_id: @location.id)
    @insert.save
end
```

The ajax in campaigns.js

```
  $('[name=commit]').bind "click", ->
    # Insert the code to allow for a user to 
    alert "Relationships created"

    selectedLocations = root.table.rows(".selected").data()
    for locationSelected in selectedLocations
      location_id = locationSelected[0]
      $.ajax({
        url: "create_campaign_location_relationship/" + location_id,  
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
      })

    return
```

Campaign routes:

```
  resources :campaigns,   only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :show]

  resources :campaigns do 
    member do 
      match "/create_campaign_location_relationship/:location_id", to: "campaigns#create_campaign_location_relationship", via: 'post' 
    end 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood `_method` param. To fix you issue change your ajax req:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/create_campaign_location_relationship" + location_id,  
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json"
  })
```

Using `_method` is not necessary here. Also note, you've defined `create_campaign_location_relationship` as `get` whereas it has to be `post`.

`_method` is a hidden field using usually within form tag and generated automagically by `form_for` or `form_tag` methods. While dealing with jQuery `$.ajax({})` method, it is not necessary to use it. Also, `_method` takes a value `patch/put/destroy`.

Comment: In the routes I changed the `get` to `post` and the changes in ajax, I still receive the error 404 in the console

Comment: I meant server logs, something like `Started POST ...` and further.

Comment: That's interesting. Look at `campaigns/campaigns/...` (double `campaigns`). Having thath, remove `campaigns` from url, so that it becomes: "/create_campaign_location_relationship" + location_id` (with preceding `/`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65014/discussion-between-sauron-and-blelump).

Comment: I figured it out. I changed the route to: `match "/create_campaign_location_relationship/:location_id", to: "campaigns#create_campaign_location_relationship", via: 'get'`, so instead of `post`, using `get` allowed it to work